# Make sure c++ decimal comparison is correct

Tags: c++, double

I have two double variable. double a = 0.10000, double b = 0.1. How can I make sure the comparison (a == b) is always true ?

Comment: Avoid checking equality of two floating point numbers.

Comment: Check difference against a tolerance; the tolerance must be set depending on your particular domain.

Answer (score 4):

If you are being paranoid about using `==` on `doubles` or `floats` (which you should be) you can always check that they are close within a small tolerance.

```
bool same = fabs(a-b) < 0.000001;
```

Comment: In general, a constant tolerance is a bad idea because the amount adjacent floats differ by changes depending on the numbers themselves. https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/

Answer (score 0):

New answer to old question, but using epsilons is the way to go, check this example:

```cpp
bool equals(const double a, const double b, const double maxRelativDiff = numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()) {
    double difference = fabs(a - b);

    const auto absoluteA = fabs(a);
    const auto absoluteB = fabs(b);
    double biggerBoi = (absoluteB > absoluteA) ? absoluteB : absoluteA; // Get the bigger number

    return difference <= (biggerBoi * maxRelativDiff);
}
```

In this case you're checking if they are equal up to `maxRelativDiff`, so 0.0001 == 0.0001.
Check: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon

Comment: It even works when `a` and/or `b` is NaN. equals(NaN, NaN) is false, as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here require you to scale the tolerance factor manually, which I wouldn't advise.  For instance if you are comparing two numbers less than one millionth, one answer will always say the two numbers are "close enough."  The other answer instead leaves it to the caller to specify which is equally error-prone.

I would instead suggest something like the following function.  It will return 0 if the two doubles are within the stated range of each other, otherwise -1 (if `d1` is smaller), or +1.  Using `fabs()` may require you to link with the math library, such as with `-lm`.

```
#include <algorithm> // for max()
#include <cmath>     // for fabs()

int double_compare( double d1, double d2 ) {
  double dEpsilon = .00000001;
  double dLarger = std::max( std::fabs(d1), std::fabs(d2) );
  double dRange = dLarger * dEpsilon;
  if ( std::fabs( d1 - d2 ) < dRange )
      return 0;
  return d1 < d2 ? -1: 1;
}
```

Comment: My answer has specified a default value for the function, so it is overridable depending on the circumstances. I wouldn't say that it's more error-prone